# Mysql join columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 1 main table and two tables that hold multiple dinamyc information about the first table.

The first table called 'items' holds main information. Then there are two tables (ratings and indexes) that holds information about some values for dinamyc count of auditories and time period.

What i want:
When I query for those items, I want result to have an additional column names from ratings and indexes tables.

I have the code like this

```
SELECT items.*, ratings.val AS rating, indexes.val AS idx
FROM items,ratings,indexes 
WHERE items.date>=1349902800000 AND items.date <=1349989199000 
AND ratings.period_start <= items.date 
AND ratings.period_end > items.date 
AND ratings.auditory = 'kids'
AND indexes.period_start <= items.date 
AND indexes.period_end > items.date 
AND indexes.auditory = 'kids'
ORDER BY indexes.added, ratings.added DESC
```

The tables look something like this

items:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` bigint(40) DEFAULT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

ratings:

```
`id` bigint(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`period_start` bigint(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`period_end` bigint(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`val` float DEFAULT NULL,
`auditory` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

All dates except 'added' fields which are simple TIMESTAMPS are BIGINT format - miliseconds from whatever date it is in AS3 when you do Date.getTime();

So - what is the correct way to get this acomplished?

Comment: Your SELECT already includes columns from from ratings and indexes; what do need to add to it?

Comment: Do you want the same result but just want to validate your approach or do you want more information?

Answer (score 0):

The only  thing I'm not seeing is the unique correlation of any individual ITEM to its ratings... I would think the ratings table would need an "ItemID" to link back to items.  As it stands now, if you have 100 items within a given time period say 3 months... and just add all the ratings / reviews, but don't associate those ratings to the actual Item, you are stuck.  Put the ItemID in and add that to your WHERE condition and you should be good to go.

Comment: Well, i should get only one row from ratings in the period of time. Actually ratings is the table showing in which times the item has which ratings

Comment: @LokoTerrorita, so at any given "time", only one product can have a rating?  Even if you did from July 1 to July 15th?  You should probably edit your question and show sample data of each respective table AND what your expected answer will be.